# Jenkins build after SVN check in

Tags: jenkins, svn

Can automated build be triggered in Jenkins after SVN check in. We want to trigger and deploy the automated build to dev automatically

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins builds can be triggered from rest api. Using curl tool like ;

```
curl -X POST http://jenkinsBuildUserName:BuildUserApiToken@your-jenkins.com/job/JobName/build?token=AuthenticationToken
```

There are some configurations that needs to be applied in Jenkins(like enabling url triggers) 
This post explains these steps very clearly
 https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2015/10/triggering-jenkins-builds-by-url/

Create a bat file which has the above command and has curl in the same folder.

At the svn server side, you can configure a post commit hook which executes this bat file. Everytime you make commit this bat file will be executed then jenkins job will be triggered.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks

I suggest you to use [Multi Job Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) (or if you find a similar plugin) to include your jenkins jobs. Then you can configure jobName in the url as this root job to trigger all the jobs you want